# TSC frequency mismatch between VM and host

Tags: android, android-emulator

Recently getting this error in Android Studio 3.5, always four times when starting an emulator:

> 4:31 PM   Emulator: `qemu-system-x86_64`: warning: TSC frequency mismatch between VM (`3398030 kHz`) and host (`3398029 kHz`), and TSC scaling unavailable

`ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1` was already set - and with `ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=0` it does not start at all.

What to do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching `ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1/0` once forth and back apparently cleared the user image of the emulator (`killall qemu-system-x86_64` was required) and now that annoying error message is gone. The cause might have been recently updating the emulator's system image.

Comment: @Jose just delete the AVD and create a new one, starting off with a current system image and current version of the emulator. I'm still not certain if it was the update of the system image or of the emulator, nevertheless it seemed related to a minor version incompatibility.

Comment: For me it was enough to 'wipe data' the ADV. Strange though

Answer (score 1):

I solved with this way if your system is Linux(Ubuntu).

1. Click Activities top left button on window
2. Search "`System Monitor`" and Run it
3. Search Process Name  "`qemu-system-x86_64`" or another match with yours and kill it.
4. Execute again your Android Emulator.